How to create and manage superusers (like sysadmin) in Google Cloud SQL with SQL Server
I'm a database engineer that works most with SQL Server and with experience with SQL Server and all SQL alternatives in Microsoft Azure and AWS.
Recently I had to work with a managed SQL Server Instance on Google Cloud SQL for the first time;
Of course I had to learn all the little differences that SQL Server has on GCP...
In all google manuals and forums I was able to learn and find the answer for the obstacles that I had working for the first time with GC SQL, but there is one thing out there on the internet, there is not a real manual of google covering everything about the subject;
It is superusers! I found something about not having a sysadmin role in GC engineering, but I didn't found any solutions if I have to use a user that has to use sysadmin privileges...
I'm in a situation that I need to have full access to all system databases, but I can't grant a db_owner permissions to this type of database with the "sqlserver" default user that for what I searched is the user with most privileges, and I can't give sysadmin privileges as well!
In this type of situation, what are the answer to this problems? How can I have full (similar to sysadmin or db_owner) privileges in system dbs like master, msdb and tempdb?
